# How to find a 1-1 map from $B\to A$ where $B$ is set of all positive integers and $A$ is set of positive rationals - positive integers.

Tags: real-analysis

I have been at this for a while, I need it for a small part of my proof, any methods for finding a map would be appreciated.

Comment: If "1-1 map" has the usual meaning of "injective", then how about $f(n)=n+\frac12$?

Answer (score 0):

Asssuming that you actually want a *bijection* and not merely an "1-1 map" (which generally just means an injective function):

Call a number $n$ "spiffy" if $n=10^a+2\cdot 10^b$ where $a\ge 2$, $b\ge 2$ and $a,b$ are relatively prime.

Then consider

$$ f(n) = \begin{cases} a/b & \text{if }n=10^a+2\cdot 10^b\text{ is spiffy} \\
1/(k+1) & \text{otherwise, where }k = \#\{m \in\{1,2,\ldots,n\} \mid m\text{ is not spiffy} \} \end{cases} $$

Comment: i actually only need a 1-1 map.